# "The way I see it"

Tags: idioms

For example, I'd say

**"The way I see it, you catch on quick"**.

I wondered, "the way" in themselves are *Nouns*
but then how come do they function as an *Adverb* in this idiom?

I mean, if it were "**In** the way I see it", it would come to me more naturally.

Comment: It's not any of the words that's functioning as an adverb, it's the entire phrase—and it's not modifying a particular word in the independent clause, but the entire clause itself.

Comment: A phrase consisting of the noun "way" with some appropriate determiner can function as an adverb. It's a peculiarity of the word "way". Some more illustrations are in [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/226203/6700).

Answer (score 1):

> **The way I see it,you  catch on quick**.

**The way I see it**  is a noun phrase modifying the noun clause that follows( you catch on quick.)

**The way** is correct and idiomatic  here.

In the way sometimes  means impediment

He stood in the way or in my way has got negative connotations.

Answer (score 0):

> The way I say it, ...

The entire phrase is a **noun phrase**. There is *no* adverb.