# "March to the beat of one's own drum" Positive or Negative

Tags: idioms, figurative-language

In the view of the dictionary definition, the idiom **["March to the beat of one's own drum](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/march+to+the+beat+of+your+own+drum)**, is more or less something negative which has a connotation of being inattentive, inconsiderate or reckless and even regarding someone who doesn't observe the societal norms.

- > **Example:** Look, I respect the fact that you like to march to your own drum, but do you have to make a point of **doing everything in a counter-cultural way**?

But despite this definition, I have faced some occasions in which people tend to use this idiom in a positive way too.

Please kindly let me know about it.

Comment: The link you've cited there doesn't suggest connotations as negative as "inattentive, inconsiderate or reckless." Did you get that idea from a different definition? Something else you may not be aware of: countercultural doesn't just mean "not observing societal norms" but also has a strong association (at least in the US) with political/social movements of the 1960s and 70s. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterculture_of_the_1960s

Comment: Hi @Katy. Interesting point. Thank you for letting me know about it. Just in order to elaborate why I thought so, this is a link which confirms my words: https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/march+to+the+beat+of+your+own+drum.html

Comment: The example you cited is essentially saying that the subject is doing a good thing in a bad way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with "[go your own way](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/226203/6700)," **march to the beat of your own drum** has positive and negative connotations simultaneously. The connotations of each phrase are different, though. No simple, abstract description can fully convey the connotations of either phrase. To understand them, you must follow some of the cultural landmarks that echo in people's minds when they hear each phrase.

### Thoreau

First, here is the passage from [*Walden*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yiQ3AAAAIAAJ&dq=thoreau%20walden&pg=PA430#v=onepage&q=drummer&f=false), by [Henry David Thoreau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_David_Thoreau), which is usually considered the origin of the expression:

> Why should we be in such desperate haste to succeed, and in such desperate enterprises? **If a man does not keep pace with his companions, perhaps it is because he hears a different drummer.** Let him step to the music which he hears, however measured or far away. It is not important that he should mature as soon as an apple tree or an oak.

The phrase refers to people marching in formation, their steps synchronized by a drummer whom they all hear. Now imagine that one man is out of step with the rest of the formation—he isn't "keeping pace".

The "formation" that Thoreau is referring to is the common, conventional practice of seeking money, physical comforts, and the respect of most people—which is how most people live. But some people don't care very much about conventional success. Some people feel called to unusual pursuits that most people don't respect and that don't pay much money, like joining the circus or [the life of a hobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobo). These people are "marching to the beat of a different drum" than the "drum" that guides ordinary people.

### Weirdness, Quirkiness

So, saying that someone **marches to the beat of a different drum** suggests that they are *weird,* maybe somewhat goofy, certainly idiosyncratic. It suggests that they probably will not "succeed" by conventional criteria of wealth and public respect (though in rare cases they might become extremely wealthy).

Just as with "[Go Your Own Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ul-cZyuYq4)" (1977), there is a well-known pop song called "[Different Drum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9qsDgA1q8Y)" (1967)—and the words are, again, those of a person rejecting a boyfriend/girlfriend because they think their lives need to follow different paths. In "Different Drum", the girl mainly needs to maintain her freedom and independence, which would be lost if she stayed with a boyfriend who adores her too much. The rejection in "Go Your Own Way" has a more conventional reason: "You don't care about me enough. So, you will have to do without me, i.e. go your own way."

### A description, not a prescription

Another difference between the two phrases is that it makes more sense to say *that* a person marches to the beat of a different drum, than to tell a person *to* march to the beat of a different drum. Quirky, unconventional people are not that way by choice. The phrase *explains* their odd behavior: they march differently because they hear a different drum than the one that most people hear. It doesn't make sense to tell an ordinary person to march to the beat of a different drum. Ordinary people hear the same drum that most people hear. They don't hear the "far away" drum that quirky people hear.

"Go your own way" suggests self-reliance more than it suggests quirkiness. The Frank Sinatra song "[I Did It My Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq5vVbHFxnU)" suggests that even though he chose the hard, individualist path, he still succeeded by the usual standards of wealth and respect—more than most people, perhaps. "Go your own way" makes more sense as advice—and it can even serve as a contemptuous dismissal.

Answer (score 4):

### There are Different Attitudes

The idiom "March to the beat of one's own drum" or the very similar ["March to the beat of a different drummer"](https://www.idioms.online/march-to-the-beat-of-a-different-drummer/) means someone who is unconventional, nonconformist, does things in his or her own way. Whether this is a positive or negative characteristic depends on what things those are, and perhaps even more on the attitude of the person making the comment.

Some people value conformity highly, and tend to see those who violate norms as selfish or antisocial. Other people think of the ability to make one's own choices to indicate bravery or praiseworthy resistance to the pressure of the majority.

Idioms Online (linked above) suggests that the phrase may have derived from a passage in **Walden** (1854) by Henry David Thoreau, which runs:

> If a man does not keep pace with his companions, perhaps it is because he hears a different drummer.

[phrases.com](https://www.phrases.com/phrase/march-to-the-beat-of-a-different-drummer_44856) also refers to Thoreau as the source of the idiom, as does [this bookbrowse.com page](https://www.bookbrowse.com/expressions/detail/index.cfm/expression_number/424/marching-to-a-different-drummer). Thoreau  seems to have regarded this as a good thing, but not everyone did then nor does everyone now.

For example, [this personal essay](https://www.listentothyself.com/2014/03/10/march-to-the-beat-of-a-different-drummer/) seems to regard "marching to a different drummer" in a very positive light, while [this essay by a psychologist](http://www.sylviarimm.com/article_difdrum.html) associates it with possible "determined and oppositional nonconformity", "an excuse for not fulfilling school expectations." and being "rebellious".  This difference of attitude toward the idiom is, at base, a difference of attitude toward nonconformity, and also what kind of nonconformity the speaker or writer has in mind.

#### See also:

- [the free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/march+to+a+different+drummer)
- [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/different%20drummer)
- [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/march-to-a-different-beat)
- [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/marching%20to%20the%20beat%20different%20drummer)

Answer (score -1):

First, an important fact we must start with is that "Marching to the beat of your own drummer" is an idiom. An idiom is "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual word" (oxford dictionary).

This is essential because the words taken too directly or on their face, will lead to an inconsistent meaning. The phrase "marching to the beat your own drummer" is a phrase used to describe 1)although humans are alike and sometimes measured by the same standard, it is okay to progress economically, emotionally, intellectually at your own pace; and 2) march or act according to the beat of your own drum or your thoughts, ambitions, will, heart, etc. The phrase was not meant to elicit a message of negativity. It can be interpreted as such, but that would be inaccurate because it is an idiom that has been used over time to describe a particular aspect.

Consequently, "marching to the beat of your own drummer" has been used to commend differences and acting in accordance with your own beliefs. It is an idiom used to praise someone for taking an uncommon path amongst common people. The phrase was never meant to elicit negativity.

Moreover, one could more clearly replace the idiot by asserting that a person is "selfish" or "inconsiderate" if that it was you are intending to say. It is an interesting view on English, but language is very cultural and not so literal at times.

Comment: [Alonso](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/123537/alonso) or [Alonso Arguedas](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/123534/alonso-arguedas), you should have your accounts merged if you are, in fact, the same person. Also, you should take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how Stack Exchange works. As I read it, you're not really offering anything new. Please consider [editing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/111915) a little more to bring in some new information. We like citations, so everyone knows this is not unsubstantiated opinion, but actual use.